# Error No bean named 'mvcConversionService' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am upgrading springboot 2.7 from 1.5 and using springdoc.
I can compile and generate war file but when running it in webserver, there is this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webConversionServiceProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/SpringDocConfiguration$WebConversionServiceConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcConversionService' available

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcConversionService' available
```

I am running the springboot in tomcat version 8.5.

Comment: Incompatible libraries, you are probably managing some libraries yourself, which you should either not do and let spring boot manage them. If that isn't possible (Spring Boot doesn't manage everything) you need to make sure the library version  you use is compatible with the version of Spring (Boot) you are using. Yours clearly isn't and you should upgrade that library (SpringDoc in this case).